# simultaneously coordination in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm currently trying to implement a model in Netlogo where the turtles’ behaviors depend on all of their neighbors.
My point of departure is the coordination game code provided by:
http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/2549#model_tabs_browse_info

According to this model the payoff of for the turtle is determined by introducing a variable which takes the color of neighbor as its value.

```
ask turtles [
let his-color [color] of one-of turtles-on neighbors
if color = yellow and his-color = yellow [set payoff A-yellow-yellow set alt-payoff B-red-yellow]
```

However, I need to my turtles to gain their payoff by comparing their color with all of their neighbors simultaneously. The last part is problematic due to Netlogo's default synchronic update
Can anyone guide me in how to make the update simultaneously and depending on all of the neighbors, or does someone have a reference to a place where this is discussed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect all colors before changing any of them.  E.g.,

```
turtles-own [nbr-colors]

to go
  ask turtles [
    set nbr-colors [color] of neighbors  ;get list of current colors
  ]
  ask turtles [
    set payoff compute-payoff nbr-colors
    set color anything-you-want
  ]
end
```